# Passing text from Textfield to another ViewController

Tags: swift, uitextfield, segue, uisegmentedcontrol, uicontainerview

I have several ContainerViews, and users are able to move between them by tapping on the Segmented Controll. Each of this ContainerView has its own number of different textFields.

So, here's the question: how is it possible to pass text from textField in one ContainerView to another textField in another ContainerView? For example, user is typing something in the textFeildOne in the ContainerViewOne, then he switches to another ContainerViewTwo, using Segmented Controll, and this text appears in the textFieldTwo there

I couldn't figure out how to do it with segues, so please, could you help me?

Comment: Welcome to [https://stackoverflow.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/)
! At this site you are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Good Luck!

Comment: you can use the notification to send data. but I would suggest to have view controller instead of container view so that you can use view methods like viewDidLoad(), viewWillAppear()

Comment: MVC is a very common way of structuring a program.  If you create a Model object to hold shared state information, you don't have to worry about passing data among objects that come and go...each controller can ask for what it needs, when it needs it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use protocol and delegate to communicate from two view of your app.
If you don't know what i'm talking about i suggest you too check this [link](https://medium.com/compileswift/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef) .
when youu implemented ur custom protocol and delegate/delegates you can call your method (defined in your protocol) in the textfield action outlets named "valueChanged".

Comment: The problem is that I have 4 ContainerViews and a lot of textField inside of them, so it will be complicated, I think. I already have referencse to all of this ContainerViews in my main ViewController through prepare(for segue:sender:) for other purposes. I tried to implement what I want with if statements/case, but it didn't work out. Maybe there is another way, without delegation?

Comment: Well, I decided to try your method. But what do you mean by saying "you can call your method (defined in your protocol) in the textfield action outlets named "valueChanged"? I should add a method on textField with Event "Value Chaged", and inside of this function implement function from protocol, which is changing the value of the textField. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes but you don't have to implement the method inside the textField action but in the class where you want to receive your data.
Inside the textFlied method u have only to call the method by the delegate like this :
    delegate.nameOfYourMethod(data)
'data' is what u want to receive in the class where you implemented the protocol method that u defined.

Comment: I guess I understood what did you say... but for some reasons it doesn't work. Can check please my new topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45079663/delegate-text-from-textfield-between-container-views?noredirect=1#comment77132524_45079663) where I show my code? I have already implemented all this stuff